# How can I use a websocket to report the progress of POST file uploads with Fast API

Tags: post, websocket, fastapi

Taking the [file upload](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/) and [websocket](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/websockets/) examples from Fast API, consider a POST route:

```py
@app.post("/uploadfiles/")
async def create_upload_files(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    data = [file.filename for file in files]
    return process_data(data)
```

And consider the websocket

```py
@app.websocket("/ws/{client_id}")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket, client_id: int):
    await manager.connect(websocket)
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            await manager.send_personal_message(f"You wrote: {data}", websocket)
            # Replace with update based on process_data() status

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        manager.disconnect(websocket)
```

How can I update the websocket on the progress of any post requests for a given client_id?

I've looked through dependency injections and background tasks, and I can't seem to figure out a way to do it.

Ultimately, the tool I'm trying to build:

1. User uploads multiple files on client side
2. Server processes the files (which can take minutes to hours), and will ultimately return a single file to the user (e.g., redirect to download the file)
3. Meanwhile, I'd like the user to be updated on the progress on the data processing (e.g., via websockets).
4. If the user closes the tab (client side disconnect), the original data proecss job is stopped.

I've read about polling and other approaches, but it seems like web sockets ought to work.

Comment: Bump ! Did you ever manage to make this work ? I have the exact same problem, coming from Flask where I cowardly shared a global across the @app.route() calls.
I can't see a way out with the asynchronous workers of FastAPI :/